# How do I read transpositions?

Tags: group-theory

My text book says that $(16)(253) = (16)(23)(25) = (16)(45)(23)(45)(25)$.  I understand how to read the disjoint cycles $(16)(253)$, which means $1 \rightarrow 6, 6 \rightarrow 1, 2 \rightarrow 5, 5 \rightarrow 3, 3 \rightarrow 2$, but how do I read these non-disjoint cycles.

Comment: Read them as function composition

Comment: Read right to left!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read them *from right to left*, and apply them as ordinary functions.

Example: Given $(16)(45)(23)(45)(25)$, trace each number:

$1$ goes to $6$ via the last transposition, others leave it unchanged.

$2$ goes to $5$, which goes to $4$, which goes back to $5$.

$3$  goes to $2$ via the third transposition, the other  transpositions leave it unchanged.

$4$ goes to $5$, that goes back to $4$.

$5$ goes to $2$, which goes to $3$.

$6$ goes to $1$.

So the final transposition is $1 \to 6, 6 \to 1$, $2 \to 5 , 5\to 3, 3 \to 2$, and $4 \to 4$. So your answer would be $(4)(16)(253)$, which is correct.

Comment: I am going to choose this as the best answer because I understood what was going on.  Thank you.

Comment: @PiccolMan Thank you. I wanted to make my answer elaborate enough.

Answer (score 2):

Read them as function composition. For example,

$$(123)(34)(46)\color{red}6=(123)(34)\color{red}4=(123)\color{red}3=2$$

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing here.  Can you please add a few more steps? Thanks

Comment: I am just applying the permutation to the 6-th element.

Comment: So are you saying that 6 goes to 2?

Comment: In the final step, yes.