# Are these permutations equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

> Are the following permutations equivalent?
>
> $$(ab)(ac) = (ab)(c).$$

On the left, product of two transpositions, on the right product of a transposition and an identity permutation
Since $a \rightarrow a \rightarrow  b, b\rightarrow b\rightarrow a, c\rightarrow c$

Comment: No. $(a\ b)(a\ c)=(a\ c\ b)$.

Answer (score 2):

On the LHS, we have

$$
a\stackrel{(ac)}{\mapsto} c\stackrel{(ab)}{\mapsto} c,
$$

whereas, on the RHS, we have

$$
a\stackrel{(c)}{\mapsto}a\stackrel{(ab)}{\mapsto}b,
$$

so the two cannot be equal.

---

Alternatively, if $(ab)(ac)=(ab)(c)$, then, since we can cancel $(ab)$ by multiplying on the left by $(ab)^{-1}=(ab)$, we get

$$(ac)=(c),$$

which is clearly false.

Answer (score 2):

$(ab)(ac)$ sends:

- $a\rightarrow c $
- $c\rightarrow a$ and then $a\rightarrow b$
- $b\rightarrow a$

The final transposition would be $a\rightarrow c$, $c\rightarrow b$ and $b\rightarrow a$, so we have $(ab)(ac)=(acb)$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979429/how-do-i-read-transpositions/1979433) for more examples).

Answer (score 1):

Without doing any computations, we can see that they cannot be equivalent, by looking at [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation):

the left side is even, and the right side is odd.